# Legacy SQLite application

Tags: sqlite

I should start by saying that this is my first experience with SQLite.  I inherited an application that came bundled with sqlite.dll from 2005 and sqlite3.dll from 2007.  I'm able to get it running on a modern desktop running Windows 10 and an older desktop (32-bit) running Windows 7, and the older desktop runs the databases processes about 10x faster than the newer one.

Is there a relatively painless solution to get the modern desktop version up to speed?  I thought perhaps I could just substitute the old dll's for new ones, but of course that didn't work because the application is set for the 32-bit version.  The app won't run with the new dll's.  My guess is that the modern 64-bit version is not utilizing the 32-bit dll's very efficiently and causing the speed problem, but I don't see an easy solution.

So I guess my question is two fold: i) is my conclusion about the source of my problem plausible and ii) is there an easy fix (easier than say, rewriting the database code?)

Comment: So, to answer part of my question, no my conclusion was invalid.  I was able to test on a third system that also ran a 64-bit Windows OS and SQLite ran fine.  The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: exactly, there is no reson for SQLite to work significantly slower on newer OS. it looks more like something machine related. SQLite is a file database, so its speed is highly dependant on disk I/O. ie if there is some process already taking a lot of disk I/O, your app will work slower.